# Server creating UDP routing loop

Tags: linux, routing, udp

Our Ubuntu 16.04.6 server is receiving UDP packets from a distant machine (the packets destination address is our server)

When the UDP receiver (a simple C program receiving UDP packets and discarding them) is active -- after a few minutes -- I see tons of **duplicate packets**.

*It's as if the server rejects the packets and they get broadcast into the network*. Then another router on the network reduces the TTL and re-sends the packet to the destination and the loop continues (surprisingly, the original router delivering the packet does not forward it again. It's another router we use for testing)

Packet captures on the Ubuntu host never show any packet leaving the host except for occasional ICMP destination unreachable packets sent to the original sender (which is ignoring them).

Any ideas?

Comment: What MAC addresses are seen in captured packets?

Comment: Destination MAC is my host. Source MAC for the first packet is my default gateway. The duplicate packets arrive from another router. By the way, the host is  a VM on a VMWare ESXi if it matters.

Comment: Is it hard to try same software in the same network on physical machine (it is not important which one)? At least it will be clear if it has something to do with ESXi or not.

Comment: Probably a good idea. The original source had been terminated. I'll see if I can recreate the problem without it.